# Adding dynamic properties to datastore object

Tags: python, google-app-engine, properties

I'm relatively new to Python, coming from the PHP world. In PHP, I would routinely fetch an row, which would correspond to and object from the database, say User, and add properties to it before passing the user object to my view page.
For example, the user has properties email, name and id. 
I get 5 users from the database and in a for loop, I assign a dynamic property to the user, say image.

This doesn't seem to work in Python/Google App Engine datastore models (I think it has to do more with the datastore model than python) in a for loop. It works within the for loop (meaning I can reference user.image within the for loop, but once the for loop ends, all of the objects seem to not have the new attribute image anymore.

Here is a code example:

```
# Model
Class User(ndb.Model):
   email = ndb.StringProperty()
   name = ndb.StringProperty()


# And then a function that returns a list of users
users = User.get_users()

user_list = []
# For loop 
for user in user:
   # For example, get image
   user.image = Image.get_image(user.key)
   user_list.append(user)

   # If I print or log this user in the for loop, I see a result
   logging.info(user.image) # WORKS!

for ul in user_list:
   print ul.image # Results in None/ATTR Error
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening and how to achieve this goal?

I've searched the forms, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: This should definitely work. Are you sure this is the exact code? You're not doing anything in between the first and second loops which might cause the instances to be re-fetched from the datastore?

Comment: get_users() is probably a query and in that case the second loop will refetch the users without the dynamic properties.

Comment: Daniel, you're right! My mistake guys, I was printing the entire object and for some reason (maybe you can explain that), only the original properties print out. However, if I make a direct call to the dynamic property, like above (print ul.image), it works. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Expando Model](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#expando)

> Sometimes you don't want to declare your properties ahead of time. A
>   special model subclass, Expando, changes the behavior of its entities
>   so that any attribute assigned (as long as it doesn't start with an
>   underscore) is saved to the Datastore.

Comment: Thanks, Shay that is a possible solution and perhaps will end up being the best one. However, my understanding of the Expando class is more for Putting dynamic properties to the datastore than it is adding properties for display on view pages, right?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using the Expando for classes that don't need it from a datastore perspective (to avoid the risk of accidentally putting properties to entities that aren't supposed to have them)